# dpkg -l | grep linux-image warning and memtest86

Tags: dpkg, memtest

I have executed

```
dpkg -l | grep linux-image
```

After that I deleted the old kernels with the command

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-image-3.19.0-32-generic
```

I kept  `linux-image-3.19.0-**37(and33)`
and at the end of the purging process I got following message:

```
Generating grub configuration file ...
Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT
is set is no longer supported.
```

and this :

```
Found memtest86+ image: /memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /memtest86+.bin
done
```

1. What I should do about the warning?
2. Do I have to delete memtest86?

Answer (score 2):

The warning simply means you likely have an old configuration file living at `/etc/default/grub` It won't have a negative effect on your ability to boot but if it annoys you you can comment out that line. simply open the file with your favorite text editor like for instance `gksu gedit /etc/default/grub`, or `sudo nano /etc/default/grub` place the '#' symbol at the beginning of the GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT="n" line as shown in the example below.

Save the file and then issue the command `sudo update-grub` to update the auto generated boot file in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`

The warning is now gone.

I concur with @waltinator regarding `memtest` and have nothing further to add on that question.

Here's an excerpt showing that line commented out:

```
cat /etc/default/grub | grep TIMEOUT
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT="0"
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET="true"
GRUB_TIMEOUT="10"
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't ask two questions in one Question.
2. Be warned. A Warning is not an ERROR.
3. `memtest86+` is a small, bootable standalone memory test & diagnostic program. If you absolutely sure you will never wonder if you have a memory problem, you can delete it. Nearly nobody deletes `memtest86+`.